# SkinnedMeshRenderer растягивается

Tags: c#, unity3d

Изначально все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я, начинаю двигать объект, к которому прикреплен `SkinnedMeshRenderer`, то случается беда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как запретить данный изгиб по бокам?
Чтобы по бокам не тянулся, а только вниз или вверх?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, уже какой день не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, просто нужно было использовать `transform.LocalPosition`, за место `transform.position`.